# Перенос игры на мобильную платформу

Tags: android, html

Есть небольшая игра, которая состоит из JS, CSS, HTML, PHP.

Есть ли какие-то готовые программы которые перенесут её с легкостью на платформы Android и iOS, или лучше для них код писать вручную?

Comment: Это браузерная игра? Я думаю что имеет смысл сделать только обожку, а игру запускать в WebView. Да и прийдётся немного подпилить под мобильные экраны. А вот по поводупортирования, как по мне не самый лучший вар, если что-то и найдёте, получите, багнутую проблему, которую в итоге всё-равно перепишите на томже Unity

Comment: да браузерная,значит понял что лучше переписать заоного под андроид